# Clearing pixels of font path in HTML <canvas>

Tags: css, image, fonts, html5-canvas

I would like to know how I can create a colored canvas but with transparent parts with the font. I want the font to create a hole in this canvas. Is this possible and how ? My goal is to create the impression that an image is embbed in a font...

Thank you :)

Comment: Why not using `text-shadow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<canvas>` offers something called composite operations for cut off and such effects. I believe the operation you want is called *destination out*:

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html

And here is some more technical details in the spec:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#compositing

I cannot provide you an actual working code (your use case is pretty rare), but you should be able find a *globalComposite* tutorials and with little playing with their code you can find out how to apply the operation for your case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just found a working code here :http://blog.ericzhang.com/punch-through-text-masks-with-css-and-html5/